# How to record certain summary statistics for each item in list?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, for-loop

I have a Large List named "new_files" and contained within the list are many dataframes
[image: new_files contains 81 dataframes that have 2 columns.]

I would like to make a new dataframe or table that outputs the list name ([[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7jcF.png)]], [[2]], etc.) in one column, the mean value for that list in the second column and the standard deviation in a third column.  The column with the meaningful information in this context is column 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `lapply` :

```
data <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(new_files), function(i) {
  data.frame(name = i, mean = mean(new_files[[i]][[1]], na.rm = TRUE),
                       sd = sd(new_files[[i]][[1]], na.rm = TRUE))
}))
```

A little shorter with `imap_dfr` :

```
data <- purrr::imap_dfr(new_files, 
             ~data.frame(name = .y, 
                         mean = mean(.x[[1]], na.rm = TRUE), 
                         sd = sd(.x[[1]], na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Comment: That worked.  Thank you so much, you are incredible!

Comment: Ah, thanks for the reminder.  I tried to when I made that first comment thanking you but it was on a several minute cooldown.